# How to finalize an image render without it completing the render samples

Tags: rendering, image

I have an Intel Pentium PC that is taking 13hrs+ to render 2048 samples. It has completed 1900/2048. I'm satisfied with what I have. How do I end the rendering and just save my image file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, wait for denoising or post-process (if any)

You can then view the render and save it <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]